# Xing api throws CORS error

Tags: angularjs, api, oauth, xing

I am trying XING apis with test keys from my web application.I am on my way to implement contact import from xing using angularjs in front end.But it is not possible call any apis ,throwing error like xmlHttpRequest not allowing my site to access xing apis.

How can i make it call??

Comment: can you open your local app by double click on index.html file and try if works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CORS error.We cant overcome cors errors from client because we are calling from some domain to a protected another domain. As a solution for xing implementation we need to make xing api calls from server side.